# Dynamic object anonymous type Azure DynamicTableEntity

Tags: c#, wpf, azure, datagrid, anonymous-class

So I'm doing a exercise with wpf and getting data from azure table but I am using the DynamicTableEnity to query the cloudtableclient. A big issue comes in trying to covert the results that come back to a object that can be displayed in the Datagrid of WPF.

This requires a list of object, which I don't know what object comes back BUT I have all the data in the properites of the DynamicTableEnity. So my first hack at this was as follow.

```
List<dynamic> dynamicList = new List<dynamic>();
foreach (var entry in tableStorageEntry)
{
    var dictionaryObject = AzureConversionHelper.Converstion(entry);
    var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(dictionaryObject);
    dynamic foo = JObject.Parse(json);
    dynamicList.Add(foo);
}

public static object Converstion(DynamicTableEntity entity)
{
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    dictionary.Add("PartitionKey", entity.PartitionKey);
    dictionary.Add("RowKey", entity.RowKey);
    dictionary.Add("TimeStamp", entity.Timestamp.ToString());

    foreach (var prop in entity.Properties)
    {
        dictionary.Add(prop.Key, prop.Value.PropertyAsObject);
    }

    return dictionary;
}
```

I had no idea what I am doing and it was kind of a struggle since I haven't worked much with anonymous objects. My hack was to convert the properties into a dictionary of strings convert them into a json string and then parse them back into a dynamic object. . . . . that sounds really bad even in my head but after a couple hours of slap around articles of anonymous types I came up with that idea.

This granted how horrible it is works, so its a start for me but it becomes a real issue when I am pull down large set of data, and it makes task almost painful since I'm almost doing a triple read through the data. Can anyone point me to a better method or maybe some pointer on how to better approach this issue.

Comment: Can you not design a `class` or series of them to represent the exactness of the `object`?

Comment: Well I am trying to accommodate any table I talk to so the current subscription that I am testing has 40 entity in it which I don't have access to.

Comment: Well you can replace `public static object Converstion` with `public static Dictionary<string, object> Converstion` (which `Conversion` is spelled wrong), then I'm not sure why you convert it back to a `dynamic` when it will **always** be a `Dictionary<string, object>` in that case. I would just leave it as is once you have `dictionaryObject` and add it to your `List<dynamic>` which can be changed to a `List<Dictionary<string, object>>`. All of these are semantics; however.

Comment: Oh excuse my spelling mistake. Reason why i didn't leave it as a List of dictionary is because data grid only takes in one dimension, it doesn't like nested collections.

Comment: So then, what *exactly*, is the issue?

Comment: The issue is that I have to go through serializing the dictionary into a json string that will be formatted into a dynamic object format. I was wondering if there was a way that I didn't have to do that conversion.

Comment: If you don't want to do that conversion, than use `dynamic` everywhere instead of strong-types.